# Fetching specific URL with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match, href

This is my code :

```
$patt = "#href=\"(.*?)\"#";
preg_match($patt,$data,$match);
echo $match[1];`
```

i.e. theres a URL in the HTML code of the page `$data`

```
<a href="http://aba.ai/iEU9x">
```

I want to grab this link above. Thanks

Comment: so... what's the problem?

Comment: i want the outpus as when i echo $match[0] i want to get http://aba.ai/iEU9x only, there are many http links in $data, actually $data is the source code of a index.php of some site.

Comment: To extract data from a web page's source code you need to understand skeleton of that page. 

Is `<a href="http://aba.ai/iEU9x">` in a `<div>, <ul>, <strong>, <h1 id='header'>` please provide index.php's source code to us